# Issue tracker for blind users

Tags: issue-tracker, accessibility

I'm working on a project for blind and visual impaired people.

Now we are looking for an issue tracker that our testers (blind and visual impaired) can use with a screen reader like JAWS.

Some of our testers also want to keep track of the development progression on some issues. So we need more than post and forget.

I've looked around for different systems, but nearly all lack this functionality since most are web based.

So my question is if anyone knows a good issue tracker that support screen readers?

Comment: "but nearly all lack this functionality since most are web based": What does that mean? Why is being Web-based a problem here? -- Which solutions did you try/test so far?

Comment: If web based software is not preferred, what operating systems are the testers using?

Comment: Please rewrite your question with a good bulleted list of requirements. One of them is the suitability for a screen reader. And remove all non-essential text.

Comment: @Simon, do all of your users use JAWs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git for your VCS I would suggest taking a look at GitIssues, https://github.com/jwiegley/git-issues/tree/master, it has no current maintainer but should meet your needs:

- Written in python so cross platform
- Issue tracker is part of the same repository as the source code you are tracking
- Command line interface so suitable for screen readers
- You can extend it, *(or possibly even offer to take over the maintenance)*.